# Как проложить маршрут с помощью Google Maps в iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-api

Добрый день! Я интегрировала в свое приложение google maps и прокладываю на карте маршрут от точки к точке. На карте маршрут рисуется с помощью polyline и запроса к google direction api. Но это очень не точный и не красивый способ - если дорога на карте проходит по дуге, то линия рисуется прямая(

Как сделать так, чтобы линия рисовалась более точно, то есть на дороге, а не поверх домов?

Comment: Уже был ответ на этот вопрос. Мне лично помогло:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23155305/4995378

Comment: Помогло или дать кусок программы?

Comment: Спасибо, пока не было времени проверить.. Сегодня обязательно попробую! И за кусок программы буду очень благодарна, так как сроки поджимают, чем быстрей разберусь, тем лучше. Думаю с вашим примером мне будет проще

Comment: Работает!!! Спасибо вам большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

Года 2 назад у меня была такая же задача проложить маршрут. Я пытался тоже использовать Ваш метод. Но мне он не принес желаемого эффекта. Я использовал три варианта. Пользователь может сам выбрать. Это проложить маршрут через приложение Maps (этот способ описан в книге Садун, там есть и код). Получается такой вот запрос:

```
maps://?saddr=50.039551,36.356758&daddr=50.040218,36.356968&zoom=12&directionsmode=walking
```

Второй способ - через приложение Google Maps. Это я нашел у них на сайте. Получается такой запрос:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=50.042637,36.353310&daddr=50.040211,36.356953&zoom=12&directionsmode=walking&key=AIzaSyCYDDO89sWhrgunAG6R0pcnkX3ot5Yel28
```

И наконец способ, когда маршрут прокладывается в Safari. Он всегда есть на девайсе. Тут получается такой запрос:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=50.039551,36.356758&daddr=50.040218,36.356968&zoom=12&directionsmode=walking&key=AIzaSyBrJxnPNN_nYbrL1GuWFPqvvMqTnO37ir4
```

Внешне все выглядит красиво. Пользователь может в Maps или Google Maps выбрать вариант и типа карты и типа транспорта. Там много разных возможностей, которые повторить в своем приложении сложно.  Согласен, это не совсем ответ на Ваш вопрос. Но возможно он даст импульс для размышлений.

[MKDirections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/index.html) - решение проблемы.
[Тут](http://www.iostute.com/2015/09/how-to-show-driving-route-direction-on.html) есть подробный пример. И не только как проложить маршрут, но и разместить аннотацию на карте.

Comment: спасибо. Вариант открывать в другом приложении мне конечно не подходит, но все равно спасибо!

Comment: кстати, сейчас изучал книгу "iOS 8 Swift Programming Cookbook". На странице 434 (Chapter 9: Core Location, iBeacon, and Maps)  есть такая фраза: "Directions to walk or drive can be displayed only in the Maps app on a device, so you cannot display them inside an instance of a map view in your app." Так утверждает автор.

Comment: думаю он просто не рассматривает другие варианты, поэтому так и пишет)